# Android Studio: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextField'

Tags: android

I am making (was trying to) some changes into an existing Eclipse project.
I imported into studio, and added dependencies.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.uniapps.prayer.times.almoazin"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-2.4.1.jar')

//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
//    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0"
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.+"
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'

}
```

I landed into following errors, moment i change the sdk versions less than 23, i get errors of Material design.

Please help!

Thank you in Advance.

```
E:\Workspace\Intern\Prayer Timing\Pray Timmings\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
Error:(199, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchResultListItemHeight'.
Error:(199, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchDropdownBackground'.
Error:(199, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewCloseIcon'.
Error:(199, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewAutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(199, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQuery'.
Error:(199, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQueryBackground'.
Error:(199, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewGoIcon'.
Error:(199, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewSearchIcon'.
Error:(199, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextField'.
Error:(199, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextFieldRight'.
Error:(199, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewVoiceIcon'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchDropdownBackground'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchResultListItemHeight'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewAutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewCloseIcon'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQuery'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQueryBackground'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewGoIcon'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewSearchIcon'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextField'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextFieldRight'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewVoiceIcon'.
Error:(269, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchDropdownBackground'.
Error:(269, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchResultListItemHeight'.
Error:(269, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewAutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(269, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewCloseIcon'.
Error:(269, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQuery'.
Error:(269, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQueryBackground'.
Error:(269, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewGoIcon'.
Error:(269, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewSearchIcon'.
Error:(269, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextField'.
Error:(269, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextFieldRight'.
Error:(269, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewVoiceIcon'.
Error:(628, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'spinnerMode'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**styles.xml**

I am sharing file over drive. I would really appreciate any help.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByICCiyBOzYwQ2ZwcG5iNGlPZG8

Comment: post the activity class and it's layout

Comment: I am sorry , i don't know to which activity is this style linked to? There are a lot of activities.

Comment: Error is with attr only with name starting with search, I have no idea, please guide me, how can I know which activity to share with you. Appreciate your consideration, Ojonugwa!

Comment: try to make dependencies are compatible with build tool versions.your dependencies are higher than build tool

Comment: Dear brahmy, I did updated and checked, error is still there. Please guide me.

Comment: Do you have `attr.xml` file in your values folder?

Comment: No, Devendra! I don't have any attr.xml

Comment: bro try this in **gradle..defaultConfig {**
    **multiDexEnabled true**
**}**

Answer (score 0):

**You should avoid using + in version numbers.**

Because Android Studio says,

> Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and
>   unrepeatable builds

Try changing the dependencies in *build.gradle(Module:app)* . Replace your dependencies with the below one.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'

}
```

Comment: I appreciate, Abhinav! But unluckily it didn't solve the problem.